# Matlab: columnwise imagesc

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have an *m*-by-*n* matrix where *n* is large. I want to visualize it by using the range of values in each column, i.e. I want to visualize the whole matrix in one image but each column will have its own range. It is like applying columnwise imagesc and concatenating each column in the end.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a columnwise normalization should do the trick before you use imagesc.

Suppose you have an image called `original`.

```
original = rand(10,5);
```

First get the range of each column:

```
myMax = max(original);
myMin = min(original);
myDiff = myMax-myMin;
```

Then we shift it down to the appropriate level

```
newimage = bsxfun(@minus,original,myMin);
```

Finally we rescale it to the appropriate scale:

```
newimage = bsxfun(@rdivide,newimage ,myMax - myMin);
```

Now you can just apply imagesc to your `newimage` and I think this will give you what you need.

Note that you may want to add another step if the maximum and minimum can be equal to eachother.